# A USB keyboard in a Microserver is causing the machine to become very unresponsive

Tags: keyboard, performance

This video explains it best - [Youtube Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ed2W7nGUank&context=C3c7a524ADOEgsToPDskKQaahHO0zVCHXDV8JzSCUe)

I have purchased a number of Microservers and have finally got around to setting the first one up.

It doesn't have a PS2 port, but, has loads of USB ports. I mainly use PS2 here and could only quickly find an old Apple Keyboard.

Anyway, I started the machine up, and it was just so slow! It took slightly over 6 minutes from turning on until it got past the BIOS. However, I noticed that the BIOS was so unresponsive and slow.

Anyway, after a while, I traced it down to the keyboard I was using! The moment I unplug, boot goes from over 6 minutes to about 10 seconds! The moment I plug it back in, it goes very slow!

I have just tested this morning with my camera that charges by USB, and, I am not seeing the same issue at all - and, I find it hard to imagine that my camera is drawing less power than a keyboard.

On this basis, I have concluded that that the keyboard is simply not compatible with the Microserver.

That being said, I have never seen this issue before in my life! I was just wondering if anyone else has seen it and/or can you recommend anything?

---

## **UPDATE**

I have found another USB keyboard and the system works fine with that. I have tested the Apple keyboard again in the second system and the exact same thing happens. I am very worried about doing this again for testing in case it damages the machine, but, I am still curious as to why this is happening.

As far as I know, the Mac keyboard does work fine in other computers I have tested it on, but, there is just something wrong about using it with a Microserver. This makes no logical sense to me as I would expect it just to not work or similar rather than slow the machine down.

Anyway, leaving open for now!

Comment: I've had something similar with a specific USB key - might be related. I never worked out what the issue was though http://superuser.com/questions/95634/certain-thumbdrives-keep-a-system-from-going-out-of-the-boot-screen

Answer (score 2):

I am going with a Key is stuck on the keyboard.  And that is my final answer.
Try working all the keys on it up and down hard, to free up anything that might be stuck, including the "qualifyer" keys. or use a different keyboard.

Comment: I have to say no :( ... When I plug the keyboard in to a Windows machine, it works flawlessly, and, generally speaking, whilst I have seen stuck keys in the past, the server goes slow the moment it is plugged in, not a couple of seconds later - however, it does still work. I am able to navigate the BIOS, and type things... it is just so slow.

Comment: did you test every key while it was on the windows machine? Does this mean I dont get to play through to the next round :-)

Comment: I didn't test every button... on the chance that the power button may be the same and/or eject does something funky... but, if there was a stuck key, I am sure I would have seen something.

Comment: I tested holding down the Insert key on my keyboard, and i was still able to type in a notepad. I dont know what is on a Apple KB, but I was able to reproduce a possible scenario.  Pause and print screen too.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've seen this is when the USB device is faulty, as per psycogeek's stuck key. If you're *certain* this is not the case then I would then suggest that the port (or controller) on the device itself could be faulty. Have you tested the keyboard with the other servers?

Comment: Not with my other Microservers, but, in a PC it works fine... I will try to find/buy/get another USB keyboard and update.

Comment: Sorry, I should say that the device in "the port (or controller) on the device itself" could equally apply to the server you are testing. The port could be faulty (or wrongly configured) in bios settings on that.